# CPLEX MIP out-of-memory: NodeFileInd is 2 but no files has been created

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, cplex

I know that the CPLEX out-of-memory has been discussed a lot in the forum. However non of them could sort of my issue.

I am using CPLEX through C++ concert technology on a Widnows 7, 32-bit, 3 GB machine and I am dealing with an MIP problem. To overcome the out-of-memory issue I have set CPLEX recommended memory control parameters as below:

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::NodeFileInd,2)
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::MemoryEmphasis,true)
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::WorkMem,1024)
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::TreLim,1024)
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Threads,1)   
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::VarSel,3)
```

I have got the log from CPLEX as below:

```
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Root relaxation solution time =    9.97 sec.

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

      0     0        4.8000   290                      4.8000     6031

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =   11.97
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00
                          -------
Total (root+branch&cut) =   11.97 sec.
Warning: MIP starts not constructed because of out-of-memory status.
Error: CPLEX Error  1001: Out of memory.
```

As far as I have understood no file has been created in the working directory to write the tree on. I wonder is there any other parameter to be set to make writing the tree on a file enable.

Any comment is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it hasn't even got into the branch & cut, but hit a memory limit before that. If it hasn't started the B&C processing, it won't have processed any nodes and so there will be nothing to put in the node file?

Comment: That was my thought as well. So, in this case how I can overcome the out-of-memory issue?

Comment: Try running with just default settings. Try removing the params for workmen or trelim. Then maybe try a different algorithm for the root node, such as the barrier alg as one of the others may use less memory.

Comment: Also try watching the process using task manager or the sysinternals process explorer while it runs and see how the memory use changes - does it really hit the 3gb limit?